# Code throws NullReferenceException, but catch block not able to catch the exception

Tags: c#, exception

The code is intentionally written to throw a NullReferenceException, where the main list is initialised but the sub-lists inside the main list are not initialised.

Code is as follows:

```
List<List<string>> myList01 = new List<List<string>>(new List<string>[3]);
string[] myFruits = new string[3] { "apple", "banana", "citron" };
try
{ myList01[0].Add(myFruits[0]); }
catch (NullReferenceException e)
{ Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
```

NullReferenceException was thrown, but not caught by the catch block, as shown below
[image]

Why is this happening? How to let the catch block catch this exception?

Comment: I think `catch` does. But ONLY in Visual Studio, you can see the exception. After continuing, you wont see any side-effect in you application.

Comment: Untick "Break when this exception type is thrown". Then hit F5.

Comment: No, the exception is not caught in this case, otherwise it would be the terminal print the exception message, as in the catch block Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
With all other types of exceptions I intentional generated, catch block works and print exception message in the program terminal.

Comment: @Fildor this method still report exception left unhandled, which means catch block still doesn't work

Comment: Check your exception settings. By default it should have been set to break when a particular exception happens

Comment: VS 2022  use Debug > Windows > Exception Settings to open the Exception Settings window

Comment: Have you tried to run it in Release mode?

Answer (score 1):

> No, the exception is not caught in this case

Well, it would be caught if the code had progressed as far as handling the throw, but it hasn't yet. It will if you press F10 etc

It's breaking as soon as the exception is thrown because you've told VS to break when it's thrown:

[image]

Nominating an exception for "Break When Thrown" means as soon as it happens, VS  stops what it's doing and opens the exception helper. It doesn't run any catch handler or anything. It literally stops immediately to tell you. If you then step/run the code you'll see control jump to the catch..

> @Chandana System.NullReferenceException is ticked in the Exception Settings.

It needs to be *unticked* - these are the settings for "Break When Thrown" which is different to "Break When Unhandled" (i.e. an exception occurs and there is nowhere a `catch` that will deal with it)

When you're running with it *ticked* you'll see:

[image]

If you press F10, VS jumps to the handler and the wording changes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It's exactly the cause in this case